# How to trace all methods run by a Struts2 Web Application?

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, struts2, struts

I need to make some change to a Java-EE Struts2 Web Application written by other developers.

Since I don't know exactly how it works, I'd like to map all the actions and methods that are called on each request, to better understand the web application workflow before altering it.

Is there a way to achieve this goal ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i got from your question you may try using like this.

If you have found the action class and the `execute()`  then this could be easy for you, run the application in debug mode and start debugging from the start of `execute()` function. press `F6` to debug it line by line and if you see any new function then to go inside the function press `F5` or manually go to the function place new break point there and then press `F6` to go to that function.

Hope so it will help you

Answer (score 6):

Adopt one (or more) of the following methodologies:

1. Take a look at your [struts.xml](https://struts.apache.org/docs/strutsxml.html), to see how the [Configuration Elements](https://struts.apache.org/docs/configuration-elements.html) (particularly `Actions` and `methods`) are mapped and how, and reproduce the behavior of the application at compile-time.
2. [Write an Interceptor](https://struts.apache.org/docs/writing-interceptors.html) logging (or saving somewhere) the names of all the Actions and methods passing in the Stack, reading them from the request;
3. Implement the [Preparable Interface](https://struts.apache.org/docs/preparable-interface.html) and perform the request logging from within the `prepare()` method ;
4. Obtain the class name and method name dynamically through

   ```
   Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[level].getMethodName();
   ```

   According to the structure of your application, you can choose to put the call to this line "somewhere", to log all the class name and methods called.

   I suggest you [this implementation](http://www.swbyjeff.com/index.php/Dynamically_Retreive_Method_Name), that resolves the depth level problem for you:

   ```
   public class Utilities {
       public static String getCurrentMethod() {
           return getCurrentMethodNameFromThread(0);
       }

       public static String getCallingMethodName() {
           return getCurrentMethodNameFromThread(1);
       }

       private static String getCurrentMethodNameFromThread(int stackLevel) {
           /*
            * 0 - dumpThreads
            * 1 - getStackTrace
            * 2 - thisMethod => getCurrentMethodNameFromThread
            * 3 - callingMethod => method calling thisMethod 
            * 4 - method calling callingMethod
            */
           StackTraceElement 
               stackTraceElement = 
                   Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[4 + stackLevel];

           String className = stackTraceElement.getClassName();
           String methodName = stackTraceElement.getMethodName();

           return className + "." + methodName;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: @zzzz , could you explain your up-vote removal and fake-edits on this question and answers here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189115/the-strange-case-of-dr-upvoter-and-mr-edit ? Thanks

Comment: People tend to do so... ;) And the answer is fine, better than accepted one at least.

Answer (score 1):

*All* methods?! Or just the ones from your application?

The quickest, easiest solution (for me, anyway) would be to use AOP to instrument all your app's code, logging all entries, and possibly exits. IMO this will be more than you actually want, although it's what you're asking for. Once you have this output you can start to narrow it down to something more realistic.

(You can actually play some fun games with this, including the creation of sequence diagrams.)